# Как записать вывод команды в консоли, который постоянно обновляется не прекращаясь?

Tags: python, subprocess

Пожалуйста, помогите записать в переменную вывод команды `airodump-ng wlan0mon` (https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng)
Пытался

```
subprocess.Popen("airodump-ng wlan0mon", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
data = process.communicate()
```

и

```
output = subprocess.check_output(com, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

но безрезультатно.
Получилось запустить через `os.system("airodump-ng wlan0mon")` 
но как вывести результат в переменную, чтобы получить необходимое мне значение BSSID я не нашел/придумал

Comment: Можете более понятно сформулировать вопрос, в названии какая - то каша.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(["airodump-ng", "wlan0mon"])
```